# How to extract top 10 data in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, graph

I am new with d3.js and javascript in general and I need to take top 10 campaigns by its impressions. How can I do this?

Below is my code:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

d3.csv("ctr_impressions.csv", function(error, csv_data){
    var data = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) {return d.Campaign;})
                .rollup(function(d){ 
                    return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
                        return g.Impressions;})})
                .entries(csv_data);

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Campaign = d.key;
            d.Impressions = d.values;
        });
    var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("p")
          .text(function(d){
            return " Campaign = " + d.Campaign + " Impressions = " + d.Impressions;
          });
});
```

Thank you. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort and slice your data:

```
var topData = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.descending(+a.Impressions, +b.Impressions);
}).slice(0, 10);//top 10 here
```

Then use this `topData` for your paragraphs:

```
var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
      .data(topData)
      .enter()
      .append("p")
      .text(function(d){
        return " Campaign = " + d.Campaign + " Impressions = " + d.Impressions;
      });
```